# MS Access MTD to YTD values

Tags: sql, ms-access, sum, subquery

I am trying to calculate out of MTD values YTD per month. Here is what ive got.

In MS access i have a table with titel, date and a value (which is MTD)

```
Titel    Date      Value
User 1   1.1.2020  10
User 1   1.2.2020  5
User 1   1.3.2020  20
User 2   1.1.2020  5
User 2   1.2.2020  15
User 2   1.3.2020  0
```

I need now a new column with the YTD values:

```
Titel    Date      Value    YTD Values
User 1   1.1.2020  10       10
User 1   1.2.2020  5        15
User 1   1.3.2020  20       35
User 2   1.1.2020  5        5
User 2   1.2.2020  15       20
User 2   1.3.2020  0        20
```

I realy did a lot of googling but its hard to find a solution for this in MS Access. And yes i need to use MS Access for that :)

Thank you for your help.

EI

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In MS Access, you can use a subquery:

```
select t.*,
       (select sum(t2.value)
        from t as t2
        where t2.titel = t.titel and
              year(t2.date) = year(t.date) and
              t2.date <= t.date
       ) as YTD
from t;
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. with that sql i did not get the right result. for YTD it shows me 15, 35, 55, 15,35,55. so it sums all values per month (thats right) but no dependency on the titel (User 1, User 2 etc). i tried to extend the sql with "And t2.titel = t.titel" but this didnt work either

Comment: had a typo. with the titel = titel it works thank you

Answer (score 0):

One option uses a correlated subquery:

```
select t.*,
    (
        select sum(t1.value) 
        from mytable as t1 
        where t1.titel = t.titel and t1.date <= t.date and year(t1.date) = year(t.date)
    ) as ytd
from mytable as t
```